# fancybox - use element for caption

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to use fancybox on a fairly large site for showing popup images some of which need a caption and some not.

I'd prefer to put captions in hidden div elements as it's more flexible than using 'caption' attribute. I've used the code from [7. Customize title --> Use element instead of attribute](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions).

It works fine except that on those images where there is no caption needed and no hidden div element, fancybox then uses the title attribute from the link as a caption, so that you could end up with a caption like, eg, 'Click to enlarge'.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there a way to globally override it for the site (not image by image).

Comment: I don't think it's worth the effort seeing as JFK has linked below to a jsfiddle which shows the fix

Comment: You're right. I retract my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you mentioned, there is a condition that evaluates if there is a hidden `div` element that fancybox uses as `title` :

```
if (id) {
    el = $('#' + id);

    if (el.length) {
        this.title = el.html();
    }
}
```

The only thing you have to do is to add an `else` statement to that condition where you can override the existing `title` if the caption doesn't exist

```
if (id) {
    el = $('#' + id);

    if (el.length) {
        this.title = el.html();
    }
} else {
    // don't show any title in fancybox
    this.title = "";
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tqe6b/)** ... the last image has a `title` attribute but not a corresponding (hidden) caption.

Comment: That's looks perfect, thanks. I'll incorporate it into the code.

Is there a way to include it in the main fancybox.js file so that it would apply site-wide, or must it go within the fancybox hook in the head of each page?

Comment: Don't need to mess with the original file, add it in your own custom script (e.g. myCustom.js) and load it site-wide along with the fancybox js and css files

Comment: I cannot make the if/else script work site-wide. I take the entire javascript from the jsfiddle page linked above, paste it into an empty file and call it, say, 'fancybox-caption.js'. Within the html page I link to it after the main fancybox.js and before the simple hook to fancybox, but pages do not take the fancybox-caption script.
It only works for me if I use the above if/else script directly within each html page. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @peterh if you just copied/pasted from the jsfiddle, then you may be missing to wrap everything inside the `.ready()` method (jsfiddle's sample is in `onDomready` mode so I omitted it) ... check updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tqe6b/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could just add manually-created tooltips to the pictures after the fact with something like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) or [prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/)